# Running several instances of delphi7 ide in windows 10

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7, windows-10

I want to run several instances of delphi7 each with one software I'm making, I'm using windows 10 which it suppose virtual desktops, but they don't work like that if you create another virtual desktop and you open a .dpr file, it bring the first delphi instance.

btw with the desktops.exe app which you can create virtual desktops in windows 8, you can really make virtual desktops and run in every desktop a different delphi ide instances, but with windows10 virtual desktops you can't.
there is  a work around of this????

Comment: I don't have Windows 10, but isn't this a setting, i.e. you can choose if an app should be present on all desktops, or only on this one? That's how it works on the Mac.

Comment: As I know, it doesn't have that option setting, which is ridiculous because Desktops.exe has that feature but the super Windows 10 virtual desktops NO, it bring to the original desktop which you used to open the app.


Sisinternals Desktops uses a Windows desktop object for each desktop.